# How to terminate Application with using Sikuli

Tags: java, automated-tests, sikuli

How to terminate application with using Sikuli framework? Now I am using such construction to close It:

```
App app = new App(pathToApplication);
amm.open();
//some actions
app.close();
```

But it's not working, and application not closed. And I need some solution to close applocation in @AfterTest method to close it even if test was failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use `app.closeByKey()`, it tries to get the app to front and then use the system specific key combination (Alt-F4, cmd-Q, ctrl-Q) to gracefully close the application, which might not always be accomplished using the normal app.close().

Read the docs here 
https://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/appclass.html#App

It's available from version Sikulix 1.1.0 Below is the maven dependency for it

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sikulix/sikulixapi -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
  <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is the other approach to close the application till you get a stable release of 1.1.4:

```
app.focus();
type(Key.F4, Key.ALT); ----> For WINDOWS
type("q", Key.CMD); ----> For MAC
type("q", Key.CTRL);-----> For LINUX
```

If you want to close all apps opened then use below code:

```
for (App app : App.getApps()) {
     app.closeByKey();
  }
```

Comment: But I don't have such method, and I can't to use it.

Comment: Which version of sikuli you are using..?

Comment: I am using 1.1.2

Comment: I would suggest you use Sikulix 1.1.2. I updated my answer you can add the dependency in your project.

Comment: But I am using version 1.1.2, and it's not working, because method .closeByKey() does not exist.

Comment: I think you are using Sikuli. You need to shift to **Sikulix**. The whole project has been shifted under the name of **Sikulix**. Kindly, update the dependency and then verify by using closeByKey() method.

Comment: No I am using Sikulix. That is my dependency: <dependency>
  <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
  <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Sorry my mistake, It has been introduced in version 1.1.4-SNAPSHOT which will be available as a stable build in April month. Till then you can use the type method.

Comment: One more question please, if I will got some exceprtion, method @AfteTest will run and it will try to close application, but what if there will be few windows opened, that method will close just one window, how does it can be solved?

Comment: I have updated my answer to closing multiple apps. Please upvote it if you found it useful.

Comment: I think that method getApps() exist just from Sikulix version 1.1.4, and I can't use it. Maybe It have some anothe way to make it?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your entire application in the try...catch statements. Simply put that code in your main script:

```
try {
    // Your code goes here
    app.close();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    app.close();
    exit();
}
```

On any exception error your script will print the message and gracefully exit with closing the tested app.